# Creating a sin/cos graph with c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am writing some code in c++ to display two plots on one graph. One function needs to be a `sin` function and the other needs to be a `cos` function.

I have the code needed for the `sin` graph and `cos` graph but I can't get them to display together.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
const float PI = 3.1459265;
int main()
{
    int size = 80, height = 21;
    char chart[height][size];
    size = 80, height = 21;
    double cosx[size];
    double sinx[size];

    {
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            cosx[i] = 10*cos(i/4.5);

        for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
                if (-.01 < 10 - i - round(cosx[j]) && 10 - i - round(cosx[j]) <0.01)
                    chart[i][j] = 'x';
                else if (i==height/2)
                    chart[i][j] = '-';
                else
                    chart[i][j] = ' ';

        for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
                cout << chart[i][j];

        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            sinx[i] = 10*sin(i/4.5);

        for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<size; j++)

        if (-.01 < 10 - i - round(sinx[j]) && 10 - i - round(sinx[j]) <0.01)
            chart[i][j] = 'x';
        else if (i==height/2)
            chart[i][j] = '-';
        else
            chart[i][j] = ' ';

        for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
                cout << chart[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a charting library? it looks like your trying to just output to the console.

Comment: If you just want to quickly plot some stuff you might want to take a look at gnuplot http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/simple.html or matplotlib http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/basic_example.html

Comment: I've tried to format the code but you should check my edit in case the indentation is not correct. Although not always necessary, it's good to use braces `{ .. }` around code blocks to aid readability and make future edits easier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't print newlines after each line of your graph. Replace

```
for (int i=0; i<height; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++)
       cout << chart[i][j];
```

with

```
for (int i=0; i<height; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++) {
       cout << chart[i][j];
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

Then it works for me.

However, this seems like a somewhat convoluted way of doing it. If it were me, I'd calculate the coordinates for the x-es from the function values rather than scan and check for each coordinate if it is close to a function value. Example:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  int size = 80, height = 21;

  // Start with an empty chart (lots of spaces and a line in the middle)
  std::vector<std::string> chart(height, std::string(size, ' '));
  chart[height/2] = std::string(size, '-');

  // Then just put x-es where the function should be plotted
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    chart[static_cast<int>(std::round(10 * std::cos(i / 4.5) + 10))][i] = 'x';
  }

  // and print the whole shebang
  for(auto &&s : chart) {
    std::cout << s << '\n';
  }
}
```